Unanchor page style box in Libre Office
I’m trying to set a background image on a page in Libre Office Writer. I want to put it in a custom position, which means hitting the Apply button and checking that it’s in the right place. However, the “Page Style” box covers most of the page, and seems to be anchored in place. When I try to move it, the entire Libre Office window moves with it. It’s very frustrating.
Is there any way to unanchor the box, so I can pull it to one side (or, ideally, onto the second monitor), so I can actually see the page I’m working on.

I can move it (the page style window) to the right so that the Apply button is almost off the screen - that makes a lot of the page visible.  I can also zoom down to about 40%.  The combination of both actions allow me to see almost the entire page.
My system is Xubuntu 24.04, which means XFCE4 desktop.  My LO is downgraded to version 7.4.7.2.  LO 7.5.0 introduced an incorrect fix in September 2022 for an issue with printing a document having both portrait and landscape pages.  That fix bluntly twisted pages which resulted in large format printers (Canon iX6820 is but one example) being forced to print exclusively in landscape mode unless the paper size is very large ie Tabloid (11x17).  Reference LO bug 154975 for All printing in landscape format.

I wonder why it works for you.

@TRiG - It also works on my Xubuntu 22.04 system.  I can also move windows such as this one with Alt-spacebar.
